# How to feed large dataset into training in Tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a large dataset and I am unable to utilise all of the data in training as I explain below.

At the very start I am shortening the DF to 1/30th of the full set:

```
shortsen = int((len(main_df))/30)
main_df=main_df.tail(shortsen)
```

I then split into Train-Val-Test data:

```
main_df, test_df = train_test_split(main_df, test_size=0.1, shuffle = False)
main_df, validation_main_df = train_test_split(main_df, test_size=0.259259259, shuffle = False)
```

Then I normalise and scale data:

```
main_df,scale = CalcBox.NormaliseandScale(main_df, type = scaletype, visu='n')
validation_main_df,discardscaler = CalcBox.NormaliseandScale(validation_main_df, type = scaletype,  scaler = scale, visu='n')
test_df,discardscaler = CalcBox.NormaliseandScale(test_df, type = scaletype,  scaler = scale, visu='n')
```

Here is my bottleneck and hence why I have shortened the dataset at the start.

I am collecting the sequences and returning them as numpy arrays.
This consumes my RAM as it creates repeated sequences just 1 timestep foward and is holding it in memory (not GPU mem).

```
train_x, train_y = SequenceCollector(main_df, SEQ_DATA)#, artificalbalancing = True)

validation_x, validation_y = SequenceCollector(validation_main_df, SEQ_DATA, artificalbalancing = False, noholds=False)

test_x, test_y = SequenceCollector(test_df, SEQ_DATA, artificalbalancing = False, noholds=False)
```

From what I have understood from various reading, I should be able to save these sequences to disk and use a generator to load and train on them? A lot of the articles are around image classification models and there they are loading multiple image files - which is kinda throwing me.

I'm inexpeirenced with using generators but I get the general gist of how they work - but I am struggling to implement it...

The rest of the code is model structuring finalised with:

```
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=BATCH, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y), callbacks=[tensorboard]) #, checkpoint])
```

Comment: You can try using `tf.data.Dataset` ( [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) ) to create a data pipeline from a generator. Use the [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) method.

Comment: Yeah I've been trying to comprehend those pages.

From what I gathered I should convert the returned numpy arrays to tf.data datasets?
Then later I need to modify this?:

`def gen():
  ragged_tensor = tf.ragged.constant([[1, 2], [3]])
  yield 42, ragged_tensor`

`dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     gen,
     output_signature=(
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32),
         tf.RaggedTensorSpec(shape=(2, None), dtype=tf.int32)))`
   
Confused where I am saving to disk and then reading. Even by converting to tf.data datasets, thats after I've capped my memory